# C# Serialize data with linq for chartist.js

Tags: c#, linq, serialization, json.net

I have the following list:

```
    public class Prices
    {
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }

    List<Prices> List1 = new List<Prices>();
    List1.Add(new Prices { Year = 2018, Price = 1.5m });
    List1.Add(new Prices { Year = 2017, Price = 1.2m });
    List1.Add(new Prices { Year = 2016, Price = 3.5m });

    //The linq query i'm trying to build
     var data1 = List1.Select(c=> new
         {
             labels = new List<Int64> {c.Year },
             series = new List<decimal> {
                 new List<decimal> { c.Price }
             }
         });


    // it's what i want to build
    var data2 = new {
      labels = new List<Int64> { 2018, 2017, 2016 },
      series = new List<decimal[]> {
               new decimal[] { 1.5m, 1.2m, 3.5m }
        }
    };

    var Json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data2);
    //Json => {"labels":[2018,2017,2016],"series":[[1.5,1.2,3.5]]}
```

I wish to convert the List1 to a Json Output using linq:

> {"labels":[2018,2017,2016],"series":[[1.5,1.2,3.5]]}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a new object containing properties for `labels` and `prices` where each is populated using a `.Select()` to select the appropriate values.

```
var data = new
{
    labels = List1.Select(x => x.Year),
    prices = new []{ List1.Select(x => x.Price) }
};
var Json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on user3559349's answer, put it in a class or view model...

```
Public class ChartModel
{
    public ChartUnit[] Chart { get; set; } = Array.Empty<ChartUnit>();

    public string ToJson()
    {
        var data = new
        {
            lables = Chart.Select(s => s.Label),
            Value = Chart.Select(s => s.Value)
        };

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
        return json;
    }
}
```